# Order of rows in heatmap?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, heatmap

Take the following code:

```
 heatmap(data.matrix(signals),col=colors,breaks=breaks,scale="none",Colv=NA,labRow=NA)
```

How can I extract, pre-calculate or re-calculate the order of the rows in the heatmap produced? Is there a way to inject the output of `hclust(dist(signals))` into the heatmap function?

Comment: Related question: [Which heatmap/image to get row-sorted plot without any dendrogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562078/r-which-heatmap-image-to-get-row-sorted-plot-without-any-dendrogram)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback, Jesse and Paolo. I wrote the following ordering function which will hopefully be useful to others:

```
data        = data.matrix(data)
distance    = dist(data)
cluster     = hclust(distance, method="ward")
dendrogram  = as.dendrogram(cluster)
Rowv        = rowMeans(data, na.rm = T)
dendrogram  = reorder(dendrogram, Rowv)

## Produce the heatmap from the calculated dendrogram.
## Don't allow it to re-order rows because we have already re-ordered them above.

reorderfun = function(d,w) { d }
png("heatmap.png", res=150, height=22,width=17,units="in")

heatmap(data,col=colors,breaks=breaks,scale="none",Colv=NA,Rowv=dendrogram,labRow=NA, reorderfun=reorderfun)

dev.off()


## Re-order the original data using the computed dendrogram
rowInd = rev(order.dendrogram(dendrogram))
di = dim(data)
nc = di[2L]
nr = di[1L]
colInd = 1L:nc
data_ordered <- data[rowInd, colInd]
write.table(data_ordered, "rows.txt",quote=F, sep="\t",row.names=T, col.names=T)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are a variety of options. If you run `?heatmap` you'll see the various parameters you can tweak. Maybe the easiest is to set `Rowv=NA` which should suppress row reordering, and then pass in the matrix with the rows already in the order you want. But you can also manually provide a clustering function, or dendrograms, via `Rowv` and `hclustfun` etc...

Answer (score 4):

I believe this post might be useful:

[How does R heatmap order rows by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705250/how-does-r-heatmap-order-rows-by-default)

Take the following matrix for example:

```
set.seed(321)
m = matrix(nrow=7, ncol = 7, rnorm(49))
> m
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]        [,6]      [,7]
[1,]  1.7049032  0.2331354 -1.1534395 -0.10706154 -1.1203274  0.11453945 0.2503958
[2,] -0.7120386  0.3391139 -0.8046717  0.98833540 -0.4746847 -2.22626331 0.2440872
[3,] -0.2779849 -0.5519147  0.4560691 -1.07223880 -1.5304122  1.63579034 0.7997382
[4,] -0.1196490  0.3477014  0.4203326 -0.75801528  0.4157148 -0.15932072 0.3414096
[5,] -0.1239606  1.4845918  0.5775845  0.09500072  0.6341979  0.02826746 0.2587177
[6,]  0.2681838  0.1883255  0.4463561 -2.33093117  1.2308474 -1.53665329 0.9538786
[7,]  0.7268415  2.4432598  0.9172555  0.41751598 -0.1545637  0.07815779 1.1364147
```

You can override the order of the rows and columns with the parameters `Rowv` and `Colv`. You can override the order with these as dendrograms. For instance, you can calculate an order using the function `hclust`, then pass that to `heatmap` as a dendrogram:

```
 rhcr <- hclust(dist(m))
 chrc <- hclust(dist(t(m)))
 heatmap(m,Rowv = as.dendrogram(rhcr),
           Colv = as.dendrogram(rhcr))

 > rhcr$order
 [1] 1 3 6 2 7 4 5
 > chrc$order
 [1] 6 4 5 1 2 3 7
```

Gives:

[Hclust heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goUR8.png)

The default heatmap function uses one additional step, however, through the parameter `reorderfun = function(d, w) reorder(d, w)`, which reorders the dendrogram as much as possible bases on row/column mean. you can reproduce the default order with this additional step. So to get the same ordering as `heatmap`, you can do:

```
rddr <- reorder(as.dendrogram(rhcr),rowMeans(m))
cddr <- reorder(as.dendrogram(chcr),colMeans(m))

> as.hclust(rddr)$order
[1] 3 1 6 2 4 5 7
> as.hclust(cddr)$order
[1] 6 4 5 1 2 3 7
```

Which gives the same output as simply `heatmap(m)`:

[Default heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EPYS.png)

In this example the columns happen to not get reordered, but the rows do. Finally, to simply retrieve the order you can assign the heatmap to a variable and get the output.

```
> p <- heatmap(m)
> p$rowInd
[1] 3 1 6 2 4 5 7
> p$colInd
[1] 6 4 5 1 2 3 7
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Jesse. For your problem take a look at the `Rowv`, `distfun` and `hclustfun`arguments of the heatmap function.
For more choices the functions `heatmap.2` in the `gplots` package, `heatmap_plus` in the `Heatplus` package and `pheatmap` in the `pheatmap` package could be of some use.

Answer (score 1):

pheatmap will allow you to specify the method that it uses to do the clustering, accepting the same arguments as hclust.