# R: Which heatmap/image to get row-sorted plot without any dendrogram?

Tags: image, r, heatmap

Which package is best for a **heatmap/image with sorting on rows only, but don't show any dendrogram or other visual clutter (just a 2D colored grid with automatic named labels on both axes)**. I don't need fancy clustering beyond basic numeric sorting. The data is a 39x10 table of numerics in the range (0,0.21) which I want to visualize.

I searched SO (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638462/r-image-of-a-pixel-matrix)) and the R sites, and tried a few out. Check out [R Graphical Manual](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/search.php?query=heatmap) to see an excellent searchable list of screenshots and corresponding packages.

The range of packages is confusing - which one is the preferred heatmap (like *ggplot2* is for most other plotting)? Here is what I found out so far:

- [base::image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638462/r-image-of-a-pixel-matrix) - bad, no name labels on axes, no sorting/clustering
- [base::heatmap](http://flowingdata.com/2010/01/21/how-to-make-a-heatmap-a-quick-and-easy-solution/) - options are far less intelligible than the following:
- [pheatmap::pheatmap](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/index.html) - fantastic but can't seem to turn off the
  dendrograms? (any hacks?)
- [ggplot2 people use geom_tile, as Andrie points out](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/)
- [gplots::heatmap.2](http://www.compbiome.com/2010/04/r-heatmaps-with-gplots.html) , [ref](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gplots/index.html) - seems
  to be favored by biotech people, but way overkill for my purposes. (no
  relation to *ggplot** or Prof Wickham)
- [plotrix::color2D.matplot](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/images.php?show=all&query=package:plotrix) also exists

*`base::heatmap`* is annoying, even with args *`heatmap(..., Colv=NA, keep.dendro=FALSE)`* it still plots the unwanted dendrogram on rows.

For now I'm going with *`pheatmap(..., cluster_cols=FALSE, cluster_rows=FALSE)`* and manually presorting my table, like this guy: [Order of rows in heatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320814/order-of-rows-in-heatmap)

Addendum: to display the value inside each cell, see: [display a matrix, including the values, as a heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789549/display-a-matrix-including-the-values-as-a-heatmap) . I didn't need that but it's nice-to-have.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking. Are you asking how to make a heatmap in ggplot? If so, you need to use `geom_tile()`

Comment: @Andrie: I'm just asking which package you all recommend (how do I get sorting without clustering? and no dendrograms?). I didn't think *ggplot2* could do heatmaps, but after you mention geom_tile I found that [learnr article](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/).

Comment: If you just want to sort, why not use `sort()`?

Comment: (I know how to sort manually, but I thought we could get that for free with some of the heatmap fns.) Regardless, which package do you recommend for my use case?

Comment: I would cluster using `hclust` or `kmeans`, or alternatively just `sort`, then plot using `ggplot2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `pheatmap` you can use options `treeheight_row` and `treeheight_col` and set these to 0.

Answer (score 1):

just another option you have not mentioned...package `bipartite` as it is as simple as you say

```
library(bipartite)
mat<-matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),byrow=TRUE,nrow=3)
rownames(mat)<-c("a","b","c")
colnames(mat)<-c("a","b","c")
visweb(mat,type="nested")
```

Comment: Here are screenshots of [bipartite:visweb](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=bipartite:visweb). Looks nice, not sure how to repurpose the extra labeling options from their biological purpose.