# Controlling the shared legend when adding a ggplot dendrogram plot to a plotly heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, legend, heatmap

I have `genes` x `samples` expression data I'd like to generate a `plotly` `heatmap` for and add the `samples` `dendrogram` `ggplot` to.

Here are my data:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),100,10,dimnames = list(paste0("G",1:100),paste0("S",1:10)))
```

Here's the `clustering` and `dendrograms`:

```
library(dendsort)
library(dplyr)

col.hc <- hclust(dist(t(mat))) %>% dendsort::dendsort(.)
col.dend <- as.dendrogram(col.hc)
col.ord <- order.dendrogram(col.dend)
row.hc <- hclust(dist(mat)) %>% dendsort::dendsort(.)
row.dend <- as.dendrogram(row.hc)
row.ord <- order.dendrogram(row.dend)
mat <- mat[row.ord,col.ord]
```

Here I'm creating a `ggplot` from `col.dend`, using `dendextend`. Note that all `legend` associated `text` and `ticks` are suppressed:

```
library(dendextend)
library(ggplot2)

col.gg.dend <- dendextend::as.ggdend(col.dend)
col.gg.dend.ggplot <- ggplot(col.gg.dend,labels=F)+guides(fill=F)+theme_minimal()+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),axis.text=element_blank(),axis.ticks=element_blank(),panel.grid=element_blank(),legend.position="none",legend.text=element_blank(),legend.background=element_blank(),legend.key=element_blank())
```

And here I'm creating the `plotly` `heatmap` and adding `col.gg.dend.ggplot` using `plotly::subplot`:

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
library(grDevices)

plot.df <- reshape2::melt(mat,varnames=c("gene","sample"),value.name="value")

heatmap.plot <- plot_ly(z=c(plot.df$value),x=plot.df$sample,y=plot.df$gene,colors=colorRamp(c("darkblue","white","darkred")),type="heatmap",colorbar=list(title="Expression",len=0.4)) %>%
  layout(yaxis=list(title="Gene"),xaxis=list(title="Sample"))

empty.axis <- list(showticklabels=F,showgrid=F,zeroline=F,title=NULL)
empty.plot <- plot_ly() %>% layout(margin=list(l=200),xaxis=empty.axis,yaxis=empty.axis)
subplot(plotly_build(col.gg.dend.ggplot),empty.plot,heatmap.plot,nrows=2,margin=c(0,0,0,0),heights=c(0.2,0.8),widths=c(0.8,0.2))
```

which gives me:
[image]

All of this works nicely except for having the bottom part added to the `heatmap` `legend` `(black,solid,1)` and `(NA,1)`, which I'd like to remove/suppress.

Note that `plotly_build(col.gg.dend.ggplot)` draws the `dendrogram` without that `legend` part.

Comment: Vaguely related: [Which heatmap/image to get row-sorted plot without any dendrogram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562078/r-which-heatmap-image-to-get-row-sorted-plot-without-any-dendrogram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relatively simple workaround is to do:

```
subplot(col.gg.dend.ggplot,
        plotly_empty(), 
        heatmap.plot,
        nrows = 2,
        margin = c(0,0,0,0),
        heights = c(0.2,0.8),
        widths = c(0.8,0.2)) %>%
  layout(showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

The issue underlying is explained in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39948151/in-r-plotly-subplot-graph-how-to-show-only-one-legend).

> layout options found later in the sequence of plots will override
>   options found earlier in the sequence.

Since if you just reverse the order of the subplots.

```
subplot(heatmap.plot,
        plotly_empty(), 
        col.gg.dend.ggplot,
        nrows = 2,
        margin = c(0,0,0,0),
        heights = c(0.2,0.8),
        widths = c(0.8,0.2))
```

[image]

the artifact is gone.

If you manually specify the legend should not be plotted within heat-map the issue is gone:

```
subplot(col.gg.dend.ggplot,
        plotly_empty(),
        heatmap.plot %>%
          layout(showlegend = F),
        nrows = 2,
        margin = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
        heights = c(0.2, 0.8),
        widths = c(0.8, 0.2))
```

[image]

and the colorbar has shifted towards the middle, indicating the heatmap plot had an invisible legend which triggered the legend of the dendogram to appear since it was later in the sequence of subplots.

Do note that within `subplot` you need not call `ggplotly` or `plotly_build` on ggplot objects. And an empty plot can be called by `plotly_empty()`.

Another way to avoid the issue is to use `ggdendro`:

```
library(ggdendro)
d.col <- dendro_data(col.dend)

col.2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data = d.col$segments, aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())

subplot(col.2,
        plotly_empty(), 
        heatmap.plot,
        nrows = 2,
        margin = c(0,0,0,0),
        heights = c(0.2,0.8),
        widths = c(0.8,0.2))
```

yielding the same plot as the first one posted.

Answer (score 1):

The heatmaply package handles this nicely (disclaimer, I'm a contributor):

```
library(heatmaply)
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),100,10,dimnames = list(paste0("G",1:100),paste0("S",1:10)))

heatmaply(mat, dendrogram="column", col = cool_warm, key.title = "Expression", plot_method = "plotly")
```

I did notice the same issue when not setting `plot_method="plotly`, though.