# Trying to determine why my heatmap made using heatmap.2 and using breaks in R is not symmetrical

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, heatmap

I am trying to cluster a protein dna interaction dataset, and draw a heatmap using heatmap.2 from the R package gplots. My matrix is symmetrical.
Here is a copy of the data-set I am using after it is run through pearson:[DataSet](http://pastebin.com/JQ1wgVwD)

Here is the complete process that I am following to generate these graphs: Generate a distance matrix using some correlation in my case pearson, then take that matrix and pass it to R and run the following code on it:

```
library(RColorBrewer);
library(gplots);
library(MASS);
args <- commandArgs(TRUE);
matrix_a <- read.table(args[1], sep='\t', header=T, row.names=1);
mtscaled <- as.matrix(scale(matrix_a))
# location <- args[2];
# setwd(args[2]);
pdf("result.pdf", pointsize = 15, width = 18, height = 18)
mycol <- c("blue","white","red")
my.breaks <- c(seq(-5, -.6, length.out=6),seq(-.5999999, .1, length.out=4),seq(.100009,5, length.out=7))
#colors <- colorpanel(75,"midnightblue","mediumseagreen","yellow") 
result <- heatmap.2(mtscaled, Rowv=T, scale='none', dendrogram="row", symm = T, col=bluered(16), breaks=my.breaks)
dev.off()
```

The issue I am having is once I use breaks to help me control the color separation the heatmap no longer looks symmetrical.

Here is the heatmap before I use breaks, as you can see the heatmap looks symmetrical:
[image: Without Breaks]

Here is the heatmap when breaks are used:
[image: With breaks]

I have played with the cutoff's for the sequences to make sure for instance one sequence does not end exactly where the other begins, but I am not able to solve this problem.  I would like to use the breaks to help bring out the clusters more.

Here is an example of what it should look like, this image was made using cluster maker:
[image]

I don't expect it to look identical to that, but I would like it if my heatmap is more symmetrical and I had better definition in terms of the clusters.  The image was created using the same data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigating I noticed was that after running my matrix through heatmap, or heatmap.2 the values were changing, for example the interaction taken from the provided data set of

Pacdh-2
and 
pegg-2

gave a value of 0.0250313 before the matrix was sent to heatmap.
After that I looked at the matrix values using result$carpet and the values were then

-0.224333135
-1.09805379

for the two interactions

So then I decided to reorder the original matrix based on the dendrogram from the clustered matrix so that I was sure that the values would be the same. I used the following stack overflow question for help:
[Order of rows in heatmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320814/order-of-rows-in-heatmap)

Here is the code used for that:

```
rowInd <- rev(order.dendrogram(result$rowDendrogram))
colInd <- rowInd
data_ordered <- matrix_a[rowInd, colInd]
```

I then used another program "matrix2png" to draw the heatmap:
[image]

I still have to play around with the colors but at least now the heatmap is symmetrical and clustered.

Looking into it even more the issue seems to be that I was running `scale(matrix_a)` when I change my code to just be `mtscaled <- as.matrix(matrix_a)` the result now looks symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

I'm certainly not the person to attempt reproducing and testing this from that strange data object without code that would read it properly,  but here's an idea:

```
  ..., col=bluered(20)[4:20], ...
```

Here's another though which should return the full rand of red which tha above strategy would not:

```
 shift.BR<- colorRamp(c("blue","white", "red"), bias=0.5 )((1:16)/16)
 heatmap.2( ...., col=rgb(shift.BR, maxColorValue=255), .... )
```

Or you can use this vector:

```
> rgb(shift.BR, maxColorValue=255)
 [1] "#1616FF" "#2D2DFF" "#4343FF" "#5A5AFF" "#7070FF" "#8787FF" "#9D9DFF" "#B4B4FF" "#CACAFF" "#E1E1FF" "#F7F7FF"
[12] "#FFD9D9" "#FFA3A3" "#FF6C6C" "#FF3636" "#FF0000"
```

There was a somewhat similar question (also today) that was asking for a blue to red solution for a set of values from -1 to 3 with white at the center. This it the code and output for that question:

```
test <- seq(-1,3, len=20)
shift.BR <- colorRamp(c("blue","white", "red"), bias=2)((1:20)/20)
tpal <- rgb(shift.BR, maxColorValue=255)
barplot(test,col = tpal)
```

[image]

(But that would seem to be the wrong direction for the bias in your situation.)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion when I try your solution out however I get a result similar to the result I was getting before I used the breaks.  The issue there is that I loose all resolution of the clusters.  I need to use breaks, or something like it so that i can control the color boundaries, but in my case I need the heatmap that is generated to look symmetrical, but instead the top right and bottom left corners of the heatmap are different color patterns.

Comment: Actually I gave two suggestions.

Comment: True enough my mistake, when I said sugestion I meant your anwser as a whole.  I played with your other suggestions and I think it is close here is what it looks like:https://plus.google.com/photos/108505223022973601424/albums/5794041426425288545?authkey=CJbK_dTPx6OpnAE
So it looks better but the top left and top right still are not there, the other issue is I am having trouble with exactly calibrating "bias=2)((1:20)/20)" so that the color range has more definition in terms of the red.  Thanks

Comment: Looks to me that you want a non-monotonic color map, where it reaches it's densest red around 1 and stays dense red between 1 and 3. That should not bee too difficult with the methods illustrated.

Comment: Hi DWin when I stopped doing mtscaled <- as.matrix(scale(matrix_a)) and instead did just mtscaled <- as.matrix(matrix_a) the result is symmetrical.  Now I can play around with the code more.  Thank you for the advice +1.