# How does R heatmap order rows by default?

Tags: r, heatmap, dendrogram

The R heatmap() documentation says for `Rowv` and `Colv` (i.e. row and column ordering parameters):

> If either is missing, as by default, then the ordering of the corresponding dendrogram is by the mean value of the rows/columns, i.e., in the case of rows, Rowv <- rowMeans(x, na.rm = na.rm).

I thought it's as easy as that but now I guess there must be something more in the default ordering algorithm.

Let's have this correlation matrix:

```
m = matrix(nrow=7, ncol = 7, c(1,0.578090870728824,0.504272263365781,0.526539138953634,0.523049273011785,0.503296777916728,0.638770769734758,0.578090870728824,1,0.59985543029105,0.663649941610205,0.630998114483389,0.66814547270115,0.596161809036262,0.504272263365781,0.59985543029105,1,0.62468477053142,0.632715952452297,0.599037620726669,0.607925540860012,0.526539138953634,0.663649941610205,0.62468477053142,1,0.7100707346884,0.738094117424525,0.639668277558577,0.523049273011785,0.630998114483389,0.632715952452297,0.7100707346884,1,0.651331659193182,0.64138213322125,0.503296777916728,0.66814547270115,0.599037620726669,0.738094117424525,0.651331659193182,1,0.612326706593738,0.638770769734758,0.596161809036262,0.607925540860012,0.639668277558577,0.64138213322125,0.612326706593738,1))

m
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.5780909 0.5042723 0.5265391 0.5230493 0.5032968 0.6387708
[2,] 0.5780909 1.0000000 0.5998554 0.6636499 0.6309981 0.6681455 0.5961618
[3,] 0.5042723 0.5998554 1.0000000 0.6246848 0.6327160 0.5990376 0.6079255
[4,] 0.5265391 0.6636499 0.6246848 1.0000000 0.7100707 0.7380941 0.6396683
[5,] 0.5230493 0.6309981 0.6327160 0.7100707 1.0000000 0.6513317 0.6413821
[6,] 0.5032968 0.6681455 0.5990376 0.7380941 0.6513317 1.0000000 0.6123267
[7,] 0.6387708 0.5961618 0.6079255 0.6396683 0.6413821 0.6123267 1.0000000
```

The `heatmap(m)` output is:

[image]

The row (and column) order is: 1, 3, 7, 5, 2, 6, 4

However, I expected the ordering to be:

```
order(rowMeans(m))
1 3 7 2 6 5 4
```

How's that?

I guess it could have something to do with how the dendrograms are clustered. But still unsure: if I first group 4 and 6 and then perhaps work with a 6x6 matrix where one row/column is the averages(?) of the original rows 4 and 6, it still shouldn't change the mutual order of e.g. rows 2 and 5, should it?

Thank you very much for any hint!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `heatmap` help you can read:

> Typically, reordering of the rows and columns according to some set of
>   values (row or column means) within the restrictions imposed by the
>   dendrogram is carried out.

In fact the reorder using Rowmeans/Colmeans is applied to the clustres. This is done internally in 2 steps. I will plot the dendogramm in each step to show how clusters are reordred.

```
hcr <- hclust(dist(m))
ddr <- as.dendrogram(hcr)
plot(ddr)
```

[image]

Now If you reorder the dendrogram this by rowmenas we get the same OP order.

```
Rowv <- rowMeans(m, na.rm = T)
ddr <- reorder(ddr, Rowv)
plot(ddr)
```

[image]

Of course this order can be changed , if you provide a new Clustering function or order function. Here I am using the default ones : `hclust` and `reorder`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I get it - it orders the leaves of the tree so that they are as much ordered according to rowMeans as possible while preserving the tree-like topology of the structure (i.e. no crossed lines). Now the meaning of "within the restrictions imposed by the dendrogram" makes more sense to me.

Comment: P.S.: I'd like to upvote your answer, but still I don't have enough reputation to do that :-)

Comment: Just to add that reorder is not very easy to work with. You could also use "rotate" from the "dendextend" R package.

Comment: @TalGalili really? I will take a closer look at `rotate` but in what `reorder` is difficult?

Comment: reorder asks you to work hard on the weights for ordering the labels. In "rotate", you just state the order of the labels you want, and it will do the best it can.