# R heatmap underlying data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, heatmap, dendrogram

I made a heatmap for which I ordered the rows and columns manually by their respective dendrograms. Is there a way to save the underlying data frame of the resulting heatmap which has been reordered?

If it helps, Here is the code for the heatmap I created:

```
heatmap.2(as.matrix(scaled),dendrogram="column",scale="none",col=greenred(32),trace="none",key=T,cexCol=.8,cexRow=.02,
Rowv=as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(scaled))),Colv=as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(scaledt))))
```

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Where did you get `heatmap.2()`?

Comment: heatmap.2 is from gplots

Comment: I believe I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320814/order-of-rows-in-heatmap With some changea for my specific needs.